# JMSSerializerBundle - Multiple serialized names for the same properties

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm trying to do the following:

I want to have **one set of serialized names when (de)serializing xml and a different set when using json for the same properties of one class?**

I managed to do this manually by using different config files and then loading them manually using the serializer builder:

```
$serializer =
    JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()
        ->addMetadataDir($someDir)
        ->build();
```

Is it possible to do something similar using the jms_serializer service from sf container?

Is there any other smarter/easier ways to implement this?

Using duplicate properties and groups like the following is not an option:

```
.....
protected $emailAddressJson;

protected $emailAddressXML;
.....

Json yaml config:
----------------- 
    emailAddressJson:
        serialized_name: emailAddress
        groups: [json]
XML yaml config
---------------  
    emailAddressXML:
        serialized_name: EMAIL_ADDRESS
        groups: [xml]
```

Comment: I've been trying to do something similar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151442/changing-jms-serialization-json-label-names-according-to-api-level). What I resorted to, as a workaround, was to manipulate the output using an EventSubscriberInterface: that lets me add extra nodes, though I've not found an easy way to remove the ones I don't want (but for my purposes, and as a workaround, that was enough to get on with what I needed to do)